# AWS S3 fetchObjects throwing error when does not exists

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am fetching all objects from S3 and method throws exception, when given folder does not exists. how should I write the code that it provides ObjectListing as blank or null when folder is not present.

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName, folderName);
```

Comment: Can you paste the exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to see if it exists by catching an exception:

```
public boolean exists(AmazonS3 s3client, String bucketName, String folderName) {
  try {
    s3Client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, folderName);
    return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // log exception
  }
  return false;
}
```

Set `objectListing` to `null` if does not exist

```
if (!exists(s3Client, bucketName, folderName)) {
   objectListing = null;
}
```